# How to disambiguate same string between translations inside Qt/QML app and a Qt Plugin?

Tags: qt, localization, qml, translation, qtplugin

There's a Qt/QML app that uses `qsTr()` for localizing it's strings in `.qml` files and a [Qt plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications) (loaded via `QPluginLoader`) that does the same.

```
Text { text: qsTr("back") }
```

Suppose there's a same string that in app has one meaning and in the plugin it has another meaning. Both strings used in the same context (like a component `MyWindow.qml`)

```
// plugin: "back" -> go back
// app:    "back" -> not front
```

When we install different `QTranslator` into the app, they are looked up in the reverse order which means **either app translation gets overwritten by plugin** OR **plugin translation gets overwritten by app** (not to mention when 2 plugins can overwrite one another).

```
QCoreApplication::instance()->installTranslator(appTranslator);
QCoreApplication::instance()->installTranslator(pluginTranslator);
```

How to break this loop so in app it uses app translation and in plugin it uses plugin's translation?

Comment: Is that plugin based on a standard Qt plugin or is it a custom plugin? is a qml plugin?

Comment: @eyllanesc, it is a standard Qt plugin, as defined [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html). Plugin has some UI components in it's `qrc`.

Comment: What class does it inherit from (QAccessibleBridgePlugin, QImageIOPlugin, etc)? I want to create a test and I need info, if you could provide an MRE then that would be great.

Comment: @eyllanesc What class does what inherit from? It is a raw bare-bones qt plugin which inherits from it's own interface and declares Q_PLUGIN_METADATA as written [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications).

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem, my test project: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/68721681

Comment: @eyllanesc you cannot reproduce because `app.ts` and `plugin.ts` have different context. If your app will have a UI component called `MyWindow.qml` and your plugin will have the same component, both with strings translated differently, then you will repro the issue.

Comment: That detail is important, one way to differentiate the translations is the context and that is the cause of the problem. My recommendation: Don't use the same context.